# Посоветуйте правильную архитектуру приложения.

Tags: java, браузер

Кратко о проектируемом продукте: 
Интерфейс приложения - иконка в трэе, по наведению или клику на которой будет отображаться фрэйм с именем, допустим, InfoFrame.

При открытии в браузере(и только в этом случае) страницы со специфическим URL, данные из определенного div'а будут "вытягиваться" приложением и отображаться в InfoFrame'е.

Написание планируется на Java, научить "общаться" приложение хочу с Chromium-подобными браузерами и Mozilla.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, **технологии или подходы**, с помощью которых можно было бы осуществить такое связывание?
*(Еще раз повторюсь, что это не тривиальный парсинг, а отображение данных в приложении только открыт браузер && в браузере открыт определенный URL && в HTML-коде находится div с определенными аттрибутами).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экстеншен к браузеру ковыряется в DOM и вытаскивает, что нужно, соединяется с приложением в трэе любым удобным способом и отдает данные для показа. (Учитывая, что возможности экстеншенов ограничены, вероятно, это будет легковесный HTTP-сервер в приложении). Все.

Answer (score 0):

Как сделать то, что вы просите, вам уже написал Nofate. Но я задам встречный вопрос - не оказалась ли задача архитектурно переусложнена еще на стадии постановки?

К примеру, обязательна ли иконка в трее? Я имею в виду, обязательно ли нахождение этой иконки именно в трее? Что, если выводить InfoFrame средствами самого браузера? В таком случае задача сводится к простейшему браузерному расширению.

Или другая крайность - обязательно ли использование стороннего браузера? Что, если встроить браузер в само приложение - есть же встраиваемые браузеры?

Или еще один вопрос. Этот самый "определенный URL" - ваш или принадлежит стороннему сайту? В первом случае можно опять-таки выкинуть расширение из схемы.

Comment: Иконка в трее обязательна, т.к. информация должна быть видима при любом состоянии системы(кроме full-screen приложений, конечно);

Использование стороннего браузера диктуется тем, что предварительно пользователь проходит авторизацию и основная работа ведется именно в браузере. 
Обсуждаемый продукт - вспомогательная приблуда. :) 

URL для внутреннего пользования, но загвоздка в том, что приложение должно работать именно тогда, когда был совершен переход по необходым URLам.

Comment: Если вы имеете доступ к серверу - можно просто добавить на страницу скрипт, отсылающий нужную информацию непосредственно приложению, используя адрес 127.0.0.1. Только порт для приложения выберите по-случайнее. Это проще, чем делать нормальное браузерное расширение для служебного пользования.

Comment: Ничего особенно страшного в расширениях к приличным браузерам нет. Немного js-кода, немного xml-изоленты и готово. Интегрироваться с IE вот на порядок неудобнее.

Comment: @Nofate, а как же установка расширений? Их активация? Как добиться, чтобы расширение не было автоматически отключено особенно хитрым алгоритмом безопасности, как однажды у меня поступил Firefox с плагином Java (комп сильно тормозил из-за шарика на виртуалке, а браузер на плагин подумал)? И как бы сделать, чтобы Chrome не выводил сообщение о расширении не из магазина при каждом запуске? Все эти проблемы, в общем-то, решаемые - но их же надо решать.